# "File Sharing" without Shared Folders still shares folders

Tags: network, sharing

I have been experimenting with the "File Sharing" settings between two MacBooks. For some reason, unexpectedly when on the Host laptop I remove all "Shared Folders" I can still use "Connect to server" and connect to the user home directory as well as the root of the drive.

Here are screenshots from both macs. Dark mode shots are from the client.

[image]
[image]

I am simply trying to add some sort of password-protected file sharing, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: The final shot shows sharing is off, it was on, and indeed those volumes were visible with the Shared Folders list empty.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out because I was logged into the same iCloud account on both machines it gave me access to both volumes automatically.

Which is the same functionality as if you log in with Admin access.

[Mac folder which is Not Shared is shared and fully accessible from a Windows machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39343/mac-folder-which-is-not-shared-is-shared-and-fully-accessible-from-a-windows-mac)